# Chrome/Webkit inspector set watchpoint?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, web-inspector

In the Google Chrome inspector:

1) I have a watch expression
2) which is not in the global scope
3) so I set a breakpoint to access its value.

But breakpoints stop the program from executing. Is there a way to not have to stop/start the program to access the watch expression value?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Nope. You must be in the same scope of the variable to know its value. If the script keeps on running, it will get out of the scope eventually. Tip: use `console.log`.